# python compile for exec

Tags: python, exec

I am using compile with exec to execute a python code specified by user. Below are 2 cases reprsenting the usert code that needs to be compiled. The user code is read into a string and then compiled as shown below. The compile works fine for case 1 while it throws a syntax error - "SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character" for case 2

case 1 (works):

```
if len([1,2]) == 2:
 return True
elif len([1,2]) ==3:
 return False
```

case 2 (fails):

```
if len([1,2]) == 2:\n return True\n elif len([1,2]) ==3:\n return False
```

compiled as:

```
compile(userCde, '<string>','exec')
```

Any ideas?? 
Thanks!!

Comment: What are you asking? The second string simply isn't valid Python code.

Comment: use triple quoted strings with code 1

Comment: If I remove the blank before "elif" I get a "return outside function"

Comment: What are you **really** trying to do? Why can't the user just, you know, call up a Python prompt and use it?

Answer (score 1):

You have a space after the `\n` before the elif, causing the elif block to be indented, and therefore, a syntax error.

Comment: Now that you mention it, yes, although that may as well be a typo. It doesn't address the actual error message ("SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character") though.

Comment: As an aside, I'd avoid this practice.  Letting users enter arbitrary strings like this and attempting to execute them will be unreliable at best, and dangerous at worst.

Comment: I think the SyntaxError you mention is due to what g.d.d.c is saying about the space before the elif.  Also I agree; be careful letting users execute arbitrary Python without limiting the builtins, etc.

Comment: @xitrium: Then think again. That issue causes an `IndentError: Unexpected indent` or something like that. The "unexpected character after line continuation character" is caused by `\...`.

Answer (score 1):

In case 2, there's an additional space before `elif` that causes this error. Also note that you can only use return inside a function, so you need a `def` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the spaces: I checked the following and it works:

```
template = "def myfunc(a):\n{0}\nmyfunc([1,2])"
code = "    if len(a) == 2:\n        return True\n    elif len(a) ==3:\n        return False"
compile(template.format(code), '<string>','exec')
```

gives `<code object <module> at 0280BF50, file "<string>", line 1>`

edit:
   did you do know the [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) function?

Answer (score 0):

Print your code as `print repr(code)`, If you `\n` is printed as `\\n` instead of `\n` that is the source of your problem: compile interprets `\n` not as a end of line, but as two characters: a line continuation `'\'` followed by an `'n'`