# How to call all function in a single command

Tags: python

Ive search the internet for my question sadly, i couldn't find any answer. here is the code.

```
print('a. sugar b. tomato c. honey d. all')

def a_func():
    print("sugar")

def b_func():
    print("tomato")

def c_func():
    print("honey")

func_map = {'a': a_func, 'b':b_func, 'c':c_func 'd':???? }

while True:
    func_input = input("Enter a letter 'a' through 'd'!\n")

    if func_input.strip() == 'exit':
        print('goodbye! ')
        exit()

    if func_input.strip() in func_map.keys():
        func_map[func_input]()
    else:
        print("Sorry no function for that!")
```

Now, I want to call all of the functions

If i enter d

The output will be like this.

```
  sugar
  tomato
  honey
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Loop over all the values in the dictionary.

Comment: Create a `d_func()` that calls all other funcs?

Answer (score 2):

Define a function that calls all the elements in a loop, and put that in the `d` element.

```
def all_func():
    for f in func_map.values():
        if f != all_func: # prevent infinite recursion
            f()

func_map = {'a': a_func, 'b':b_func, 'c':c_func 'd':all_func }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create one more function as `d_func` and call all other functions in that.

```
def d_func():
    a_func()
    b_func()
    c_func()

func_map = {'a': a_func, 'b':b_func, 'c':c_func, 'd':d_func }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('a. sugar b. tomato c. honey d. all')
def a_func():
   return "sugar"
def b_func():
   return("tomato")
def c_func():
    return("honey")
func_map = {'a': a_func(), 'b':b_func(),'c':c_func(),'d':a_func()+'\n'+b_func()+'\n'+c_func() }
while True:
    func_input = input("Enter a letter 'a' through 'd'!\n")
    if func_input.strip() == 'exit':
        print('goodbye! ')
        exit()
   elif func_input.strip() in func_map.keys():
        print(func_map[func_input])
   else:
       print("Sorry no function for that!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) to call all functions at once with [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec):

```py
func_map = {'a': a_func, 'b':b_func, 'c':c_func, 'd': lambda:exec("a_func()\nb_func()\nc_func()")}
```

Also see:

[python compile for exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367748/python-compile-for-exec)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9547687/16136190